# Combine two key-value collections with Spark efficiently

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following key-value pairs lists (like a hashmap, but not exactly inside the spark context):

```
val m1 = sc.parallelize(List(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "d"))
val m2 = sc.parallelize(List(1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3 -> "C", 5 -> "E"))
```

I want to get something like this and do if efficiently in parallel (don't even know if it's possible

```
List(1 -> (Some("a"), Some("A")), 2 -> (Some("b"), Some("B")), 3 -> (Some("c"), Some("C")), 4 -> (Some("d"), None), 5 -> (None, Some("E")))
```

Or at least

```
List(1 -> ("a","A"), 2 -> ("b","B"), 3 -> ("c","C"))
```

How to achieve this? As I understand - I don't have efficient way to get values from the "maps" by key - these are not hashmaps really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fullOuterJoin` function:

```
val m1: RDD[(Int, String)] = //...
val m2: RDD[(Int, String)] = //...
val j: RDD[(Int, (Option[String], Option[String]))] = m1.fullOuterJoin(m2)
```

Depending on your use, you can use any variation of joins:

```
val full:  RDD[(Int, (Option[String], Option[String]))] = m1.fullOuterJoin(m2)
val left:  RDD[(Int, (String, Option[String]))]         = m1.leftOuterJoin(m2)       
val right: RDD[(Int, (Option[String], String))]         = m1.rightOuterJoin(m2)
val join:  RDD[(Int, (String, String))]                 = m1.join(m2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `join` should work:

```
rdd1.join(rdd2) //RDD[K, (V1,V2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The approved answer is correct, if you want to read about it check this Key/Value pairs article out [Key/Value pairs](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or, use union...

```
rdd1.union(rdd2).groupByKey()
```